# Не могу загрузить приложение на playmarket!

Tags: android, google-play

Вот то что оно мне пишет:

Вы загрузили APK-файл или набор Android App Bundle с объектом activity, псевдонимом объекта, сервисом или широковещательным приемником с фильтром intent, но без набора свойств android:exported. Этот файл нельзя установить на устройство с версией Android 12 или выше. Чтобы узнать больше, перейдите на developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported.

Если понижать target version до 30, тогда ругается, что необходимо поднять до 31. Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

> но без набора свойств android:exported.

Если у вас есть "широковещательный приемник ", вам стоило бы указать android:exported=true. Это есть в ссылке, которая даже указана в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Уточнение: начиная с Android 12 атрибут `android:exported` нужно явно указывать для всех компонентов. Раньше были условия, при которых значение `true` выставлялось автоматически, теперь дефолтное значение всегда `false` (компонент не виден другим приложениям не зависимо от фильтров).

Comment: Я уже разобрался спасибо! Все верно! Но приемника там нет, а все равно просит. А щас разрешения кроме к интернету в приле нет а просит политику добавить. ))

Comment: Там говорится не конкретно про приёмник, а про все компоненты (_с объектом activity, псевдонимом объекта, сервисом или широковещательным приемником_). То есть даже `MainActivity` (или какая у вас стартовая) должна иметь значение `exported=true`. Откройте манифест - студия все проблемы подсветит и даже предложит фиксы

Comment: Спасибо! Уже все хорошо )))

Comment: Дело в том что ваш Activity тоже скорее всего имеет приемник... Приемник для лауничера. exported=true не надо бездумно ставить всем компонентам, а понять что оно делает и ставить только там где нужно.

Comment: Та я и поставил там где идет запуск первой главной активити.